# how to right click to select context menu in cypress e2e testing

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I am using PRIMENG context menu data table. I want to select view and delete option from a context menu in cypress e2e testing framework.

primeng data table :- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/contextmenu

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `rightClick()`

`.rightclick()` will not open context menus native to the browser. `.rightclick()` should be used to test your app’s handling of right click related events such as contextmenu.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Cypress doesn't support right click currently. However, you can try the command below, as a workaround.

```
cy.get('#nav').first().invoke('trigger', 'contextmenu')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I used invoke('show') it's worked.